# With jQuery, why Success Callback isn't executed when a JSON is returned via Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, callback

I have the following PHP code that returns a JSON object via Ajax to the client.

```
function loadAll(){
    $knowledgeHandler = new KnowledgeLevelHandler();
    $json = $knowledgeHandler->loadAll();        
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print $json;
}
```

I have a test function assigned to the success callback of jQuery Ajax.

```
successCallback = function(data){
    alert("A");
}

options = {    
    "data": data,
    "async": false,
    "type": "post",
    "success":successCallback        
}
$.ajax(url, options);
```

When I remove the `header('Content-type: text/json');` from PHP code, the callback is executed, but when it is executed, the success callback isn't executed. What is wrong?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using a synchronous request? Maybe try asynchronous?

Comment: I don't usually set the header type, I just echo out the string e.g. echo json_encode(array("success"=>true));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to specify the returned data type as JSON in your JQuery AJAX call.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> The json type parses the fetched data file as a JavaScript object and
>   returns the constructed object as the result data.

```
successCallback = function(data){
    alert("A");
}

options = {    
    data: data,
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: "successCallback",
    dataType: "json"
}

$.ajax(url, options);
```

Your successCallback function will now contain a data object, through which you can access your variables; data.var_1, data.some_other_var, etc.

Neal

Answer (score 1):

Try telling jQuery you're expecting json back.

```
options = {    
    "data": data,
    "async": false,
    "type": "post",
    "success":successCallback,
    "dataType": "json"       
}
```

you could also add a error callback with xhr, msg, code as the args and output those to get a better idea of what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
options = {    
    "data": data,
    "async": false,
    "type": "post",
    "success":successCallback,        
    "dataType: "json"
}
$.ajax(url, options);
```